# Multiple keywords, multiple tables. How should my SQL look like? (screenshot attached)

Tags: php, mysql, keyword, multiple-tables

I have these tables in my database:

```
Contacts
   -contact_id
   -contact_name

File
   -file_id
   -file_code
   -customer_id
   -hauler_id

File_details
   -file_id
   -loadunload_id
   -loadunload_date
   -loadunload_time

LoadUnload
   -loadunload_id
   -loadunload_place
```

And these inputs as search fields on my webpage. Results are sent through Ajax, the whole system will run in an offline local network:

```
"File Code" (file.file_code)
"Customer Name" (contacts.contact_name)
"Hauler name" (contacts.contact_name)
"Load place" (loadunload.loadunload_place)
"Load date" (loadunload.loadunload_date)
"Unload place" (loadunload.loadunload_place)
"Unload date" (loadunload.loadunload_date)
```

Which should get me the following results on my screen:

```
File Code | Customer | Load place | Load time | Unload place | Unload time | Weight | Hauler
```

One filled in search field should show a result as wel as multiple filled in search fields. All I really need is my file.file_id. With that I can show everything else I need in my html table, but I don't have a single clue how my SQL should look like. My guess is I need about a million joins in my sql?

I've attached a link with a screenshot, which may make things easier to understand. [Screenshot link](http://view-media.be/brain_buster.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `File.customers_id` is the foreign key for `Contacts.contact_id`, the `sql` should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM File AS f
    JOIN Contacts AS c ON (f.customers_id = c.contact_id)
    JOIN File_details AS fd ON (fd.file_id = f.file_id)
    JOIN LoadUnload AS l ON (fd.loadunload_id = l.loadunload_id)
```

This should return all entries. For filtering add a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE f.file_code = '<filecode>' AND ...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You'll need a `GROUP BY f.file_id` or else you'll get the same file multiple times (there's a many-to-many relationship between `File` and `LoadUnload` tables).